# WPF Grid Items and Right Aligned Text

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I have a WPF form where I'm trying to make a simple input form.  Two labels, two textboxes, and a "submit" button.  I have the layout pretty good, the only thing that I can't get is for my "Labels" to be right aligned inside their cells.  I have tried both TextAlign="Right" and HorizontialAlign="Right", that moves the text ALL the way over, overlaying my textbox, not just moving inside the cell.  Below is the XAML for the window.

```
<Window x:Class="MyWebKeepAliveDesktop.Login"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MyWebKeepAlive Desktop - Login" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="true" Height="200" Width="400" >

    <Border Background="#50FFFFFF" CornerRadius="7" BorderBrush="{StaticResource WindowFrameBrush}" BorderThickness="2,0,2,2">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Background="{StaticResource WindowFrameBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" Margin="-1,0,-1,0" MouseLeftButtonDown="DragWindow">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,2,10,2" 
                            Text="MyWebKeepAlive Desktop Login"/>
                    <Button Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" FontSize="7" 
                  Width="15" Height="15" Padding="0" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Width="350" Height="130" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock  TextAlignment="center" Text="Please provide your username/password that is used on the MyWebKeepAlive.com site to login." TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                <TextBlock Text="Username" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBox Name="txtUsername" Width="150" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
                <TextBlock Text="Password" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="2" />
                <TextBox Name="txtPassword" Width="150" Grid.Row="2" />
                <Button Name="btnLogin" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="Login" />
                </Button>
            </Grid>            
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: To your Grid tags add: ShowGridLines=True this should help you view the limits of your rows and columns

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your grid only has one column as written. It will need two to support your setting of Grid.Column=1 for the text boxes. Thus, you need to add a `<ColumnDefinitions>` block. With the XAML the way it is now, WPF just throws both controls into the same column, hence the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks Peter!  Intellisense confused me by not showing the "ColumnDefinitions".  I though that was what was needed, but thought I was missing something!  All is good!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with. Just learning WPF myself. As [PeterAllenWebb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/922906/179669) mentioned, your main issue is you are missing the `ColumnDefinitions`. I also added the `TextAlignment="Right"` attributes to the two `TextBlocks`.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Width="350" Height="130" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="center" Text="Please provide your username/password that is used on the MyWebKeepAlive.com site to login." TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <TextBlock Text="Username" TextAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBox Name="txtUsername" Width="150" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
            <TextBlock Text="Password" TextAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="2" />
            <TextBox Name="txtPassword" Width="150" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Button Name="btnLogin" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <TextBlock Text="Login" />
            </Button>
        </Grid>
```